# Running raw command in container shell VS command using /bin/bash -ac in shell, not giving the same result

Tags: bash, docker, makefile, docker-compose, aws-cli

When doing `docker exec -it [container_id] /bin/bash`:

I ran the following below:
Please assume folder `test/data` exists.

`root@6f200d5b9691: for file in $(aws s3 ls s3://foo-bucket | awk '{print $NF}') ; do aws s3 cp foo-bucket/${file} test/data && tar -xzf test/data/${file} -C test/data/ ; done`

For this, I got all the files under the relevant path and extracted!

However, when doing exactly the same via shell in this manner:
`root@6f200d5b9691: /bin/bash -ac "for file in $(aws s3 ls s3://foo-bucket | awk '{print $NF}') ; do aws s3 cp foo-bucket/${file} test/data && tar -xzf test/data/${file} -C test/data/ ; done"`

I get weird error such as:
`/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token foo1.tar.gz'`
`/bin/bash: -c: line 1: foo1.tar.gz ; do aws s3 cp s3://foo-bucket/foo1.tar.gz 'test/data' && tar -xzf 'test/data/foo1.tar.gz' -C 'test/data/' ; done'`

Any idea why does it happen?
What am I'm doing wrong?

The second option to run via `/bin/bash -ac "[commands here]"` is important as I want to use it in via command like:
`docker-compose run [service_name] /bin/bash -ac "[...]"`

Comment: Why does this have a `makefile` tag?

Comment: @MadScientist: Because this command intended to work under makefile, eventually

Comment: If so it would be good to mention that because when you put this into a makefile recipe you'll have to do more work (`$` is a special character in makefiles, so you'll have to escape all the ones you want to pass to the shell as `$$`)

Comment: @MadScientist: yes thanks I wasn't aware of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run

```
bash -c "file=foo; echo $file"
```

nothing is printed because `$file` is expanded (to nothing) before `bash -c` gets to see it.

The solution is to use single quotes:

```
bash -c 'file=foo; echo "$file"'
```

Now, `bash -c` gets to see the whole argument unmodified.

For your case, this means

```sh
bash -ac 'for file in $(aws s3 ls s3://foo-bucket | awk "{print \$NF}"); do
    aws s3 cp foo-bucket/"$file" test/data \
        && tar -xzf test/data/"$file" -C test/data/
done'
```

where the whole string is single-quoted. This allows for proper quoting of `$file`; for the awk command, we have to escape `$NF` because we use double quotes. An alternative for that is

```
awk '\''{print $NF}'\''
```

to get a single quote into a single quoted string.

Comment: Thanks, what about `$(aws s3 ls s3://foo-bucket | awk "{print \$NF}")` sohuldn't the first `$ `be escaped also?

Comment: Great this command worked good, but in the same syntax, under makefile not parsing ok, can you please give an example for running this under `makefile`?

Comment: @JavaSa The first `$` in `$(aws s3 ...)` doesn't need to be escaped because its context is a single quoted string where nothing expands. As for running in a Makefile, "not parsing ok" doesn't give me a clue of what's wrong. Maybe ask a separate, new question?

Comment: Yes you are right, anyway I found my way. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

$() and $var inside double quota resolves before executing the command.
So $file will be resolved not inside new bash, but before sending string to bash. So I believe $file will be empty in this case.